# How to simplify a nested loops?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have 2 ranges I am currently looping through.

```
$arr1 = range(1500, 1505);
$start = 1;
$end = 10;

foreach ($arr1 as $block) {

  for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {

    echo $block . $i; // output -> 15001,15002,15003 ... 15011, 15012 ...

  }

}
```

Is there an easier / more efficient way to do this?

Comment: you really want `150010` and `150110` etc ?

Comment: Yes, so I want to iterate through those sets of numbers. 15001,15002,15003 ... 15011, 15012 ...

Comment: but those seem to break the pattern, im confused, look at my demo, that's the exact output you want?? https://ideone.com/ZlwfTS

Comment: That looks correct to me. Can this be simplified?

Comment: What is the issue you have with the current code? Is it currently producing the desired results? Are you intending to skip from `15019` to `150110` instead of `15020`?

Comment: @fyrye - Nothing wrong with it, it works. It produces several arrays, and I would ultimately like it to produce a single array. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
for($start = 15001; $start < 15061 ; $start = $start + 10 ) {
    $arr = range($start, $start + 8);
    $arr[] = $start * 10;
    echo implode(" ", $arr) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

However, I still not get the pattern you trying the create...

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more efficient approach would be to create the entire range at once. Then use `modulo` to determine the values divisible by `10`, and use mathematics to output the desired alternative value.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/L10Jq

```
foreach (range(15001, 15060) as $v) {
    if (0 === $v % 10) {
        echo ($v - 9) * 10 . \PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $v . ' ';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
15001 15002 15003 15004 15005 15006 15007 15008 15009 150010
15011 15012 15013 15014 15015 15016 15017 15018 15019 150110
15021 15022 15023 15024 15025 15026 15027 15028 15029 150210
15031 15032 15033 15034 15035 15036 15037 15038 15039 150310
15041 15042 15043 15044 15045 15046 15047 15048 15049 150410
15051 15052 15053 15054 15055 15056 15057 15058 15059 150510
```

To create a single array, pass the value `$v` by-reference, remove the `echo` calls and  re-assign the value in the conditional.

```
$ar = range(15001, 15060);
foreach ($ar as &$v) {
    if (0 === $v % 10) {
        $v = ($v - 9) * 10;
    }
}
```